# How to get render window back on main screen?

Tags: directx, render, vvvv

I've opened a  v4 patch that's kind of old. It defaults to fullscreening when I open the patch. When I ALT+ENTER to exit fullscreen, it disappears. I'm assuming it is going to a monitor that is no longer connected.

Is there a command in the vvvv IDE to position the DirectX window back on the main screen?

Comment: eh, the only solution was to reconnect a monitor-- have not found a better way yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the patch window is still visible. There is a node called 'Window.' Run the help file and find the render window that ahould be in the list if you cycle throuh getslice. You can then move the point on the IObox around and it should reappear on you main screen. Technically its probably just slightly unclickacble off screen but I appreciate the annoyance of this.